# forall - Prolog

Tags: prolog

Can someone explain how should the predefine predicate `forall` to find the minimum values within a list?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a list `L`, you can use:

```
member(Min,L), forall(member(N,L), N>=Min).
```

However, while this is a nice demonstration of `forall`, it is not efficient (square complexity instead of linear).

Answer (score 4):

or you can use the predicate findall/3

```
findall(Value, minimumValues(Value), minimumValuesList)
```

it returns a list (minimumValuesList) with elements (all the minimum values, right).

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use `forall/2` to find the minimum?!

For the standard (linear) solution for picking the minimum/maximum/... element from a list look at SWI-Prolog's `min_list/2`:

```
?- listing(min_list).
lists:min_list([], A, A).
lists:min_list([A|C], B, E) :-
        D is min(A, B),
        min_list(C, D, E).

lists:min_list([B|A], C) :-
        min_list(A, B, C).
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
minlist([X], X).
minlist([H|T], Min) :-
    minlist(T, Tmin),
    Min is min(H, Tmin), !.
```